# How to use OKHTTP in main java

Tags: java, android, http, okhttp

This is a simple GET method in **[okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)** :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
  Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url(url)
      .build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response.body().string();
}
```

I put this code in main java file.

So where should i call it into the onCreate method?

I don't know how can i use it. For example i want to use it in the onclicklistener of a button.

Comment: *For example i want to use it in the onclicklistener of a button.* then why didn't you put the code there?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I get error. I used to use request without function but still gives my error in logcat and dieing app.

Comment: Well, what is the error? NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yeah. I think it needs a thread . yeah?

Comment: Yes you cannot use network on the main thread, you need to use an AsyncTask or something like it. Google it and you will find answers

Comment: @TimCastelijns tnx, I used a thread. And i have this error now: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokio/Okio** How can i solve it? Why OKHTTP needs that library?

Comment: I don't know. Better check the docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download okHttp jar file and include it in your project if you are using eclipse or add the dependency in your build.gradle if you are using android studio. You can find the instructions here - http://square.github.io/okhttp/

It is better to create a common Util class for networking and write common methods HTTP requests (GET, POST etc) so that they can be called from anywhere within the application by just passing the parameters which are required.

Now if you want you can add it to on onclicklistener

Sample example -

```
public class GetExample {
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

String run(String url) throws IOException {
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
return response.body().string();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
GetExample example = new GetExample();
String response = example.run("https://raw.github.com/square/okhttp/master/README.md");
System.out.println(response);
}
}
```

For onClickListener you can write below code in AsyncTask or new Thread (I hope you know how to write AsyncTask or new Thread ) -

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url(url)
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
String reponse = response.body().string();
```

Comment: Thank You. What should i write in onclicklistener ?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check